# Datatable columns is not responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i am using datatables and it is working fine, but when i have large set of columns then columns are goes beyong table limit.

[image]

as you see when i add more columns all shape table is destroyed, i have 40 to 50 columns that is displayed upon demand, please tell me how to fix it ?

it is my datatable code:

```
$('#society-table').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,

        ajax: {
            url: '/FrontEnd/resources/getplots?id='+id,
            dataSrc: '' 
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns('.select-filter').every( function () {
                var that = this;
                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        },
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "propertyNumber" },
                    { "data": "size" },
                    { "data": "balloted"},
                    { "data": "boundaryWall" },
                    { "data": "electricity" },
                    { "data": "file" },
                    { "data": "sewerage" },
                    { "data": "suiGas" },
                    { "data": "waterSupply" },
                    { "data": "communityCentre" },
                    { "data": "foodCourt" },
                    { "data": "securityStaff" },
                    { "data": "plotLaunchedDate" },
                    { "data": "price" },
                    { "data": "plotDimensions" },
                    { "data": "noofLanes" },
                    { "data": "roadSize" },
                    { "data": "plotFrontFace" },
                    { "data": "plotBack" },
                    { "data": "plotFront" },
                    { "data": "plotByLaws" },
                    { "data": "plotByLawsFile" },
                    { "data": "plotLocationPicture" },
                    { "data": "plotLocationPictureDate" },
                    { "data": "ownerName" },
                    { "data": "status.name" },
                    { "data": "type.name" },


              {
              "data": null,
              "className": "dt-center",
              searchable: false,

              orderable : false,
              render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                  return '<a href="javascript:ShowPlotssFeaturesDetails('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Show Details</a>';
      } },
      { "data": "map_x_axis" },
      { "data": "squareFeet" },
      { "data": "urbanMarlaSize" },
      { "data": "ruralMarlaSize" },
      { "data": "address" },
                    {
                      "data": null,
                      "className": "dt-center",
                      searchable: false,
                      click: false, 
                      orderable : false,
                      render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                      return '<a href="javascript:editPlot('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Edit</a> / <a href="javascript:removePlot('+row.id+', '+meta.row+')">Delete</a>';
                      } }
                   ] 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="societiestable" style="display:none; font-size: 11px; overflow:auto;">   
<table id="society-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot No</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Size</th>
                <th class="select-filter">balloted</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Boundary Wall</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Electricity</th>
                <th class="select-filter">File Name</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Sewerage</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Sui Gas</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Water Supply</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot Category</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Food Court</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Security Staff</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot Launched</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Price</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot Dimensions</th>
                <th class="select-filter">No of lanes</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Road Size</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot Front Face</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot Back</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot Front</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot by laws</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot by laws file</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot location Picture</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Plot location Picture Date</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Owner</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Status</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Type</th>
                <th>Features</th>                
                <th>Map Position X_Y_axis</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Size in Square Feet</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Size in Urban Marla</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Size in Rural Marla</th>
                <th class="select-filter">Address</th>
                <th>Edit/Delete</th>
            </tr>
   </thead>
     <tfoot>
     <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Plot No</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>balloted</th>
                <th>Boundary Wall</th>
                <th>Electricity</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Sewerage</th>
                <th>Sui Gas</th>
                <th>Water Supply</th>
                <th>Plot Category</th>
                <th>Food Court</th>
                <th>Security Staff</th>
                <th>Plot Launched</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Plot Dimensions</th>
                <th>No of lanes</th>
                <th>Road Size</th>
                <th>Plot Front Face</th>
                <th>Plot Back</th>
                <th>Plot Front</th>
                <th>Plot by laws</th>
                <th>Plot by laws file</th>
                <th>Plot location Picture</th>
                <th>Plot location Picture Date</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Features</th>
                <th>Map Position X_Y_axis</th>   
                <th>Size in Square Feet</th>
                <th>Size in Urban Marla</th>
                <th>Size in Rural Marla</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Edit/Delete</th>
            </tr>
     </tfoot>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the html and CSS for this view.

Comment: i have post the html and css

Comment: If your refering to the "Search" and "Previous/Next" section then that code isn't included.  My guess is that they are either separate elements such as a  div or table and are bound by a width in the css.

P.S. I don't see the CSS

Comment: there is no any other CSS of this table.

Comment: i am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: have you somewhat made any edit on the core files of datatables? are you sure all files needed for datatables are added css and jQuery? what version are you using?

Answer (score -2):

Are you talking about the space difference between the header and footer annotated by the red arrows? [image: In this image?]

If so, then the html isn't complete.  Also, there must be CSS that is styling this.  Otherwise it wold never look as it does.

Comment: when i use less columns then this table is shown correctly but when i show more columns than columns are goes beyond the table borders, this all thing HTML, CSS is manage by datatable api.

Comment: The HTML you posted does not represent either the top or bottom elements I highlighted with the red arrows in the picture. Also, there is CSS. Without it the HTML would not look like it does.  

If you don't post all of the html and css helping you is impossible.  Sorry that's just how it is.

Comment: you don't need to write html of top or bottom element, it created automatically when .Datatable() function is called, i think you are not understanding datatable API

Comment: Regardless of if you need to write it, it still exists along with the associated CSS.  If the top or bottom elements aren't doing what you expect it's not the API

Comment: Regardless of if you need to write it, it still exists along with the associated CSS.  If the top or bottom elements aren't doing what you expect it's not the datatable's API that's at fault It's your understanding of how the entire page works.

Forget the JavaScript/DataTable API etc and take a look at the HTML and CSS first.  For all you know those two elements could have been styled to only be 10em wide.